# Repair a huge file to which I have ssh access

Tags: ssh

I have that huge file on a remote server to which I have access through ssh. I downloaded it on my computer, but for some reason some part of it was corrupted during the transfer. Downloading it again would be very time-consuming.

As I have access to both files, I could, for instance, md5sum the first half of it and compare it to the local md5 then download only the first part. I was wondering whether anyone had a better solution.

Comment: What about using torrent? (Create a .torrent from source, load up the torrent on your machine, and let it download the missing parts.)

Comment: @Shiki interesting idea. Will the torrent blocks be compared using checksums ? I am afraid the torrent way of checking is size-based (I really have no idea to be honest)

Comment: Read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent#Creating_and_publishing_torrents ||| So basically, you will just transfer the missing and corrupt files. **BUT: You will need to run a torrent client on the server to "seed". If you can't do that, the torrent way is a no-go.**

Comment: You need to identify how it's broken before we can suggest a fix.

Comment: Doesn't rsync handle this?

Comment: @AlanCurry that’s how I ended up fixing it. Please edit an answer and I’ll give you the response point. I had to add parameter -c to the rsync command to enforce checksum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rsync should work about as well as a bittorrent in this case and with less setup required.